# LINQ метод Join() возвращает только первое значение удовлетворяющее условию а не все

Tags: c#, linq, join

Здравствуйте столкнулся с такой проблемой при обработке перечислений с помощью LINQ метода Join() возвращается не все возможные варианты удовлетворяющие условию а только первое найденное. известно что таких соединений 5 шт.

```
var path = pathOnStart
    .Join(pathOnChestToExit,
        p => p.Value,
        g => g.Value,
        (p, g) => new { p, g, l = p.Length + g.Length });
```

pathOnStart и pathOnChestToExit перечисления связных списков `IEnumerable<SinglyLinkedList<Point>>`.

вот код самих списков

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public readonly T Value;
    public readonly SinglyLinkedList<T> Previous;
    public readonly int Length;

    public SinglyLinkedList(T value, SinglyLinkedList<T> previous = null)
    {
        Value = value;
        Previous = previous;
        Length = previous?.Length + 1 ?? 1;
    }
```

Comment: Покажите исходные данные, которые вы соединяете. Соединение производится по совпадению ключей, то есть в данном случае `Value` из обоих перечислений.

Comment: данные получаю из метода который точно работает. проверен тестами и сдана задача) `IEnumerable<SinglyLinkedList<Point>>` вот сигнатура перечислений
`  
  public class SinglyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
  {
   public readonly T Value;
   public readonly SinglyLinkedList<T> Previous;
   public readonly int Length;

   public SinglyLinkedList(T value, SinglyLinkedList<T> previous = null)
   {
    Value = value;
    Previous = previous;
    Length = previous?.Length + 1 ?? 1;
   }
`
это сам связный список. и в отладке есть одинаковые списки больше одного

Comment: То есть в `Value` у вас некие классы? А у них `Equals` переопределён? Или вы уверены, что там именно одинаковые экземпляры объектов лежат в двух разных перечислениях?

Comment: да `Equals` переопределен в классе поинт. И он работает хорошо

Answer (score -1):

решение нашел. Как решил: `IEnumerable<SinglyLinkedList<Point>>` привел к виду `List<SinglyLinkedList<Point>>` и все заработало, мое предположение что при создании переменной `IEnumerable<T>` она создается лениво и почему-то join не проходит после первого найденного условия. тоже самое происходит с `foreach` вложенным в `foreach` если входные перечисления `IEnumerable<T>`. Если кто знает почему это именно так работает может рассказать или дать ссылку на материал прям по этой теме. Спасибо тем кто пытался найти решение.

Comment: А, ну да, `IEnumerable` можно перебрать только один раз. А тут видимо нужно декартово произведение, т.е. перебор со сложностью `O(N*M)`.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` и правда является ленивой последовательностью, но ваш код не должен от этого зависеть. Предположу, что ваша реализация `IEnumerable<T>` у `SinglyLinkedList<T>` ошибочна.